# How to replace a specific property value in all css classes/properties that have that value using WordPress child theme/css customizer

Tags: css, wordpress

I installed a theme and now I want to customize the CSS using Additional CSS/CSS customizer functionality in WordPress.

So, I need to replace all values in properties in all elements that have the value #123456 into #abcdef (for color in this case).

Right now, I'm finding each separate element to change the value/color, but I wish I can replace them all somehow.

This is how I do it now:

```
.text-primary {
    color: #abcdef;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #abcdef;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #abcdef;
}
```

But instead of finding each separate class/id/element that has the value #123456, and replacing it with #abcdef, I want to replace all values that are #123456 in the stylesheet.

The idea is like this:

```
* {
   ??? #123456 -> #abcdef ???
}
```

I can not use:

```
* {
    color: #abcdef;
}
```

because that would replace all elements with property color into #abcdef. 
I want to replace just those properties that have the property value #123456. Also, sometimes different properties can have the value #123456.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Copy it all into an editor --> run find and replace?

Comment: Maybe CSS Custom Proerties are the solution. https://css-tricks.com/switch-font-color-for-different-backgrounds-with-css/